Select disk in dispart via GUID/permanent hash
I hate that Windows drive letters move around for USB disks.
So how can I reference a disk in diskpart by hardware hash id?
Relative numbering is hard to script, especially if I have drives with same size:
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          232 GB      0 B

I need something like
DISKPART> SELECT DISK=023BC789
DISKPART> SELECT DISK=\\?\Volume{023bc789-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}

of course none of these work.
The disk you specified is not valid.


I think you could write a powershell script to do it.  I was doing it but ran out of time.  I didn't figure out how to populate the field you want but guess that you can't get the disk ID from diskpart.  I was getting everything there is to get from powershell but didn't know how to populate the param just like you.

I'm looking for an option without powershell, that's just one more thing to go wrong.

I don't think what you want is possible without using powershell or wmi to grab the details to determine the disk ID prior to inserting that disk ID into a script to call Diskpart.  But maybe more so is to state what your end goal is?  Maybe something besides diskpart is the answer.

Diskpart is very well documented. The select disk command (documented here
accepts 4 parameters
select disk={<n>|<disk path>|system|next}

The only one of interest to you would be disk path.
<disk path> Specifies the location of the disk to receive focus, for example, PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0F02)#atA(C00T00L00). To view the location path of a disk, select it and then type detail disk.

I do not know if that path is stable enough for your needs though.

It doesn't give one for USB drive Intenso External USB 3.0 SCSI Disk Device
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
